# How to use input type='file' to read word documents

Tags: html, file, input, vue.js

Users can upload their ms word files, of which the text should be displayed on another page. My html and javascript(vuejs) is like this:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type='file' v-on:click='retrieve'>
</form>
```

JS

```
retrieve: function retrieve(e) {
    var asfarasicansee = e.target.files[0]
    console.log(asfarasicansee)
```

This will return some file info as described here in the getting info paragraph: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

The only other thing I could find was this from 2001 and it only works in Internet Explorer, but my other code doesn't work in Internet Explorer:
https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/copying_from_mi

Does anyone know how to work with MS word(or any other text editor) files? How do I retrieve the text from such documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files created with Microsoft Word or some other softwares are not the one like a plain text. This means that you need to use a kind of parser to read the content of it. JavaScript of course supports binary format of data with `Uint8array` or `ArrayBuffer`, so you can read the content of files as that format and handle it with the specific parser like this: https://github.com/lalalic/docx4js.